# Can't get AutoBahn Websocket to Connect

Tags: android, autobahn

I am trying some of the websocket client libraries developed for Android usage. I am now fiddling with the AutoBahn library and can't seem to get the "example" client to connect to my server. I am using the following code:

```
          try {
         mConnection.connect(wsuri, new WebSocketHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onOpen() {
               Log.d(TAG, "Status: Connected to " + wsuri);
                mConnection.sendTextMessage("info");
            }

           @Override
            public void onTextMessage(String payload) {
               Log.d(TAG, "Got echo: " + payload);
            }

           @Override
            public void onClose(int code, String reason) {
               Log.d(TAG, "Connection lost.");
            }
         });
      } catch (WebSocketException e) {

         Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
      }
```

I sniff using wireshark and can see the tcp connection established, I can see the HTTP Get go out. But, my server isn't responding with an upgrade message. I do notice that the AutoBahn connect message (in the HTTP GET header) doesn't contain the origin field for some reason. I tried a different library which did connect, and it had the origin field in the HTTP GET. Is this a know issue, or is this simply not supported by AuotBahn ?

Answer (score 1):

Web browser do fill the `origin` field and disallow any JavaScript from manipulating `origin`. For non-browser WebSocket clients, the client can set `origin` as it likes. Hence `origin` cannot be trusted by the WebSocket server.

The presence of `origin` is not required by the WebSocket spec, and setting is currently not supported by AutobahnAndroid.

Answer (score 1):

It seams to work for me. I post my ugly unedited code below. I run server on IIS since I develop in WebMatrix.

#### Server (Node.js)

```
var express = require('express')
var http = require('http');
var wamp = require('wamp.io');
var io = require('websocket.io');

// Setup Express
var app = express(); 
var server = http.createServer(app);
app.listen(process.env.PORT);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// Setup WAMP
var ws = io.listen(9000);
var apps = wamp.attach(ws);

apps.on('call', function(procUri, args, cb) {
  //if (procUri === 'isEven') {
    cb(null, args[0] % 2 == 0);
 // }
});
```

---

#### Client(Android)

```
private final WebSocketConnection mConnection = new WebSocketConnection();

private void start() {
    final String wsuri = "ws://192.168.0.111:9000/topic5"; // Hardcoded local (Need to open a port on server)
    mConnection.disconnect();

    try {
        mConnection.connect(wsuri, new WebSocketHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onOpen() {
                Log.d(TAG, "Status: Connected to " + wsuri);
                testRpc();
            }

            @Override
            public void onClose(int code, String reason) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Connection lost.");
                start(); // Ugly reconnect
            }
        });
    } catch (WebSocketException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
    }
}

private void testRpc() {
    mConnection.call("calc:asum", Integer.class, new Wamp.CallHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onResult(Object result) {
            mDumpTextView.setText(result.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String errorId, String errorInfo) {
            mDumpTextView.setText("calc:asum RPC error - " + errorInfo);
        }
    }, 3);
}
```